# Rails - 401 (unauthorized) error - JSON to controller with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails app, I am trying to pass a JSON to a controller via AJAX, but I am running into the `401 (unauthorized)` error.  I've been researching this and trying to figure out what I've done wrong, but I can't quite tell.

First off, the AJAX itself -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "report/submission",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"))},
    data: {"report" : reportParameter}
});
```

This passes the data to the `submission` action in the `Report` controller -

```
class ReportController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:submission]

    def submission
      INSERT ENTRIES TO DB, ETC
    end

end
```

So perhaps one complicating factor is that I am requiring the `before_action` Devise login.

So the basic process is, a user completes a form, the entries are assembled into a JSON (`reportParameter`), then passed to the `submission` action which requires a successful login to complete (I know that might seem backwards, but it is necessary for this particular app).

My layout includes the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`, and I set `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in the `application` controller.

I must admit that I don't understand this well enough to be any more insightful - I get that this is an authorization issue related to the CSRF token, but I thought that setting `beforeSend` in the AJAX would address that.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, when user makes an ajax call, s/he is not logged in?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The call is made before they are logged in, then if they are successfully logged in, the content of the JSON will be parsed out and logged in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard Rails forms (`form_tag` or `form_for`) then an easy way would be to use `jquery-ujs`. It is usually in `application.js` by default:

```
# application.js
//= require jquery_ujs
```

It automatically handles CSRF tokens and adds to jQuery's `ajax` method (the thing you are doing manually).

If you don't want to include `application.js` file to your page, then you could simply include `jquery-ujs.js` file.

If you don't want to do that as well, then the only thing I can think of is that your form is using an "old" or "not up to date" csrf token (cached forms may have them). Then, make sure your csrf tokens in hidden form are not being submitted or match the ones you are sending out in the request headers. [Here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/v1.2.1/src/rails.js#L75-L78) is to give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing.  I am trying to avoid using the standard Rails `form_tag` and `form_for`.  I have my reasons, but I'm thinking that I might need to rethink the way this whole thing works...

Comment: In that case, you can simply add `jquery-ujs.js` to your page and it should do the trick.

Comment: I'll test it out - will let you know if it works.  Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Hmmm... but jquery_ujs is already in my gemfile and the `application.js` manifest.  Is there a reason that it wouldn't be applying to the page in question?

Comment: I thought you were not including `application.js` in your pages? If you are, the other possible cause could be that you are not including CSRF tokens in your header `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`.

Comment: Well actually, you are correct - I don't intend to include `application.js` in my page, but it is there for the time being, so I'd imagine it'd be working.  Yes, the meta_tags are in the layout head.

Comment: Hmm... Look at the network "Network" tab in DevTools and make sure the right headers are being sent.